# Wifi adapter not found - Ubuntu 18.04 on Thinkpad E480 RTL8822BE

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 but wifi adapter doesn't work. It works on Windows (dual boot) and the Ethernet/wired connection works just no wifi and potentially Bluetooth.

I tried these lines:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

But I don't think that's the right driver, so I went onto https://github.com/samcv/A485-RTL8822BE-firmware and just got errors.

Does anyone know a simple fix I can use please? I'm kind of new to Linux. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: e8:6a:64:31:eb:8a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f1304000-f1304fff memory:f1300000-f1303fff

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f1100000-f110ffff
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: As @chili555, has alluded to, you have shown us output related to your Wired Ethernet Controller, which you reinstalled in your first group of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Be certain that *Secure Boot* is **disabled** in your BIOS, otherwise no software modifications will have effect.

Comment: omg dude i love you

Comment: quick question - i tried installing manjaro gnome using the same method as ubuntu but both of my usb would not boot it. would just reject and sendme back to the boot device choice screen. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get better info about that "UNCLAIMED" network controller, update your Ubuntu with the... 
**sudo update-pciids**
 ...command, then repeat the... 
**sudo lshw -class network**
 ...command. Your rig should then identify the RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter.

You might as well also do the... 
**sudo update-usbids**
 ...command, for possibly updated info on your various USB devices.

I'm not familiar with Manjaro Linux, but I'd guess that boot boohoo is related to EFI-privilege or a lack thereof.

Comment: thanks. I'm having a bit of trouble installing apps. the archive manager shows a 'an error occurred while loading this archive'. is there a permission setting i need to fix??

Comment: @Linux GM: Rather than splinter this RTL8822 thread, how about starting another and provide specific example(s) of that archive manager difficulty?

Did my above reply [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer "Mark my reply as Accepted!") your RTL8822 question?

Comment: apologies! you've been very helpful thank you!